# Firebase CLI v7.0.0 is incompatible with Node.js v6.17.1 Please upgrade Node.js to version >= 8.0.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I upgraded my Firebase CLI (firebase-tools) to version 7.0.0.  Now, when I run it, it gives me a message:

Firebase CLI v7.0.0 is incompatible with Node.js v6.17.1 Please upgrade Node.js to version >= 8.0.0

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [version 7.0.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.0.0), the Firebase CLI dropped support for node 6.  You will need to upgrade your local node version to at least version 8.  (8.0.0 actually has bugs - you should use something more modern.)

Personally, I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install and run node, as it's easy to install and upgrade, and doesn't require root access to change system packages.

Answer (score 14):

**Problem:**

Firebase CLI v11.0.0 is incompatible with Node.js `v14.17.5`
Please upgrade Node.js to `version >= 14.18.0`
just install,

1. "npm install -g firebase-tools@10.9.2"
2. "firebase init"
3. "firebase deploy"
   and it's solved.

Comment: If you are using the firebase cloud shell emulator "npm install -g firebase-tools@10.9.2" solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
Firebase CLI v11.23.1 is incompatible with Node.js `v14.17.0` Please upgrade Node.js to version `^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0`

solution:

1. Just install the latest version - https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Search environment variable in your device and click on it
3. Right click on path ****click** add** paste this --> `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
4. **Save** click **ok**
5. **Close** your **code editor**
6. **Reopen** your **code editor**

> **it worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply uninstall your node js from your pc and download current latest version of node js from  https://nodejs.org/en/download/current and than install it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).